# XDT Config Transforms - ReplaceAll?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, app-config, config, xdt-transform

I've got a custom section in my web.config file similar to this structure:

```
<Messages>
  <Message id="1'>
     <Property Name="foo" value="bar" />
  </Message>
  <Message id="2'>
     <Property Name="foo" value="bar2" />
  </Message>
</Messages>
```

I want to apply a custom transformation on this such that I can change the value of ALL instances of the Property element with Name="foo" - but I cant seem to get it to work.

I've tried:

```
<Messages>
  <Message>
     <Property Name="foo" value="updated" xdt:Locator=Match(Name) xdt:Transform="Replace" />
  </Message>
</Mesasges>
```

I can remove all the elements by replacing the Transform=Replace with a Transform=RemoveAll - any ideas how I can achieve something similar to replace all the values?

Comment: Maybe show us what you tried?

Comment: Sorry, XMl formatting got me the first time. Updated now

Answer (score 8):

It seems like Transform:Replace only replaces the first matched element from the [documentation on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx): *...If more than one element is selected, only the first selected element is replaced.* I solved this issue by using a combination of Match-Conditions and SetAttributes, something like:

```
<Messages>
  <Message>
    <Property value="updated" xdt:Locator=Condition(@Name='foo') xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" />
  </Message>
</Messages>
```

Comment: for extra clarification, from the documentation: _...The SetAttributes transform affects **all** selected elements. This is different from the Replace transform attribute, which affects **only** the first selected element if multiple elements are selected_.

Comment: It is vital to mention that the XPath isn't sufficient for this to work. The structure of XML in transformation *must* reflect the structure of XML being transformed, so if `Property` node were placed as a root of transformation it will not work. And, what is more, it works only with `SetAttributes`, `Replace` will not work either